# HealthCheck in MassTransit say Not ready: not started

Tags: masstransit

Using `AddMassTransitHostedService` a healthcheck configuration is added, but it always report unhealth even after I configured the endpoints as in the [example](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#console-app). My project is a WebApi where I don't have my consumers in a separated startup.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `AddBus`, which has been deprecated in favor of `UsingRabbitMQ` in v7.

When using `AddBus`, you have to configure the health check manually (it is done automatically when using the new v7 syntax). The previous syntax [documentation](https://masstransit-v6.netlify.app/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) shows how to configure it, in short:

```
cfg.UseHealthCheck(context);
```

Must be added so that the health checks are reported to the hosted service.